# JNI System.LoadLibrary failed on Cocoa dylib

Tags: java, xcode, java-native-interface, dylib

following JNI guidelines, I created a dylib (in Objective-C) using Xcode and expected to load it in my Java project, like the following does,

```
public class Main {
private native void done();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        New Main().done();
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("Test");
}

public Main() {
    super();
}
```

and I am getting the following runtime error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Test in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1754)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:27)
```

How could I get this fixed?

Comment: Looks like it cant find it. Try adding the full path of the library instead of the name to `System.loadLibrary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried using the System.load with full path to the library and it worked.