# Matlab not using java.library.path to load native libraries?

Tags: java, macos, matlab

Has anyone else experienced a problem where MATLAB doesn't appear to search `java.library.path` for native dependencies?

For example:

Here is my librarypath.txt:

```
##
## FILE: librarypath.txt
##
## Entries:
##    o path_to_jnifile
##    o [alpha,glnx86,sol2,unix,win32,mac]=path_to_jnifile
##    o $matlabroot/path_to_jnifile
##    o $jre_home/path_to_jnifile
##
$matlabroot/bin/$arch
```

Now I open MATLAB:

```
java.lang.System.getProperty('java.library.path')
ans =
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64
```

Ok, looks good. Now lets see whats in that folder:

```
ls /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64/
...
libmex.dylib
...
```

Ok, `libmex.dylib` (just for example) exists in that folder. Lets try to load it:

```
java.lang.System.loadLibrary('libmex.dylib')
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libmex.dylib in java.library.path
```

WHY!?

Comment: Not a solution but a possible workaround [JNI System.LoadLibrary failed on Cocoa dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255710/jni-system-loadlibrary-failed-on-cocoa-dylib)

Comment: @zellus: java.lang.System.load('/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/maci64/libmex.dylib') works as you've suggested. Still doesn't explain this loadLibrary weirdness. I've been using loadLibrary for a while without a problem...